\input{} does not work inside \longtable{}
I want to create multiple reports with dynamic tables. When I try to insert columns with \input{inputfile.tex} it gives me the errors:
"Misplaced \noalign.
\midrule ->\noalign"

and
"Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit"

But if i copy the same code from my input file to my main file, where the \input{} command is, it works fine. I dont know why this makes a difference but I need the tables to be dynamic and therefore I need the \input command to work.
Here is the code of my main.tex with all packages I use:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf, labelsep=endash,format=hang,singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright]{caption}

\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{sidecap} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\tabrotate[1]{\begin{turn}{90}\rlap{#1}\end{turn}} 

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\clubpenalty = 10000 
\widowpenalty = 10000 
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000 

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} 
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{-0.4em} 
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 


\usepackage[
pdftitle={Analyse},
pdfsubject={Analyse},
pdfauthor={Me},
plainpages=false,
pdfpagelabels,
pageanchor=false,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=blue
]{hyperref}

\usepackage[a4paper,hdivide={2.5cm,,2.5cm},vdivide={2.0cm,,2.0cm}]{geometry}



\begin{document}


\section{Überblick}

\footnotesize
\tabcolsep0.5mm
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{longtable}[hptb]{L{39mm}L{14mm}L{53mm}L{21mm}L{28mm}}
\caption{Überblick analysierte Prüfungen} \label{tab:uebersicht} \\
\toprule
Modul & Nummer & Titel & letzter Zeitpunkt & Zeitvergleich? \\
\endfirsthead 
Modul & Nummer & Titel & letzter Zeitpunkt & Zeitvergleich? \\
\midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\tiny{\emph{(Fortsetzung der Tabelle auf der nächsten Seite)}}\normalsize} \\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%%%%%%%%
\input{C:/proj/input.tex}
%%%%%%%%
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\emph{Quelle: }Campus24}} \\[-3pt]
\end{longtable}
\tabcolsep0mm
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
\normalsize

\end{document}
This is the input.tex file:
%\midrule Geschichte und Analyse der künstlerischen Medien I    &   1234    &   Geschichte und Analyse der künstlerischen Medien I  &   SoSe 2023   &   ja, s. Abschnitt \ref{prf1} \\
%\midrule Geschichte und Analyse der künstlerischen Medien II   &   1342    &   Geschichte und Analyse der künstlerischen Medien II &   SoSe 2023   &   ja, s. Abschnitt \ref{prf1} \\
%\midrule Schwerpunktmodul Museumsstudien I &   4132    &   Schwerpunktmodul Museumsstudien I   &   SoSe 2023   &   nein \\
%\midrule Schwerpunktmodul Kunst- und Kulturwissenschaften I    &   4321    &   Schwerpunktmodul Kunst- und Kulturwissenschaften I  &   WiSe 2022/23    &   nein \\
%\midrule Schwerpunktmodul Digitale Kunstgeschichte I   &   1234    &   Schwerpunktmodul Digitale Kunstgeschichte I &   SoSe 2023   &   nein \\


Using \input inside a table is always dangerous, because \input executes hooks before and after reading the file. You can try \csname @@input\endcsname input.tex.

BTW: You should not use inputenc if you are using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. And \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is not needed for several years also with PDFLaTeX.

\input works, the problem is that \midrule has to be the first thing in the row, you can not do {}\midrule or \relax\midrule  and \input{.. a file starting \midrule is basically equivlatent to that

LaTeX redefines the expandable primitive \input command, unfortunately. If you use a TeX format other than LaTeX (it doesn't redefine this primitive command) then you have no problems. LaTeX saves the primitive meaning of this command to \@@input control sequence. So the obscure solution \csname @@input\endcsname input.tex works.

@DavidCarlisle The file does not need to start with \midrule (and in the example it doesn't, because all lines are commented). The \bottomrule after the \input{…} also is not the first thing in the row.

@cabohah ah yes same thing at other end:-)
